# Pass data from one report to other report using "SUBMIT"

Tags: report, submit, abap

I have to pass the user name from one report to another report in ABAP.

I am using the following code.

```
   SUBMIT zpgm_to WITH fld_pgm2 eq fld_pgm1 .
```

'zpgm_to ' is the report to where i have to pass the value.

'fld_pgm2' is the field in report zpgm_to .

'fld_pgm1' is the field in report zpgm_from which contains the value to be passed.

While i am using debugging i found that the value is not passing to the zpgm_to report.
I could not find where i had done the mistake. If anyone cross this issue before, pls do the needful.

Comment: looks about right. Are you sure the report doesn't set default values during parameter declaration?

Comment: hi GarlandGreene, i declared the fld_pgm2 as data. So only i didnt set. Since it didnt throw exception, i didnt note that. Now after changing into parameter its working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can' t see a problem in your example code.

If you have a typo in `fld_pgm2` and you use an undefined parameter, the syntax check does not report an error.

Please try the extended syntax check:

1. Program->Check->Extended Syntax Check
2. Check if `External program interfaces` is checked.
3. Run the check. If there is a typo, you get an error `___ is not a parameter or a select option in report ___`

Comment: hi kunt, I didnt declare fld_pgm2 as parameter that was a problem. Now corrected that. Thanks for ur reply.

Answer (score 0):

Check the definition of `fld_pgm2`. it must define as **PARAMETER** ,not Data.